# GNU 64-bit assembly adding functin

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

When we have

```
add %rbx, %rax
```

Does this mean add the value of rbx to rax or add the value rax to rbx?

If for example rbx=3 and rax=6, after the add %rbx, %rax, what will be the values of %rax and %rbx?

GNU x64 assembler syntax please!

Comment: I updated the [AT&T tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info) with info like this on AT&T syntax, and a link to a good canonical duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

x86 assembly comes in two major "flavors": Intel syntax and AT&T syntax (used mostly by default by GNU tools).

Your snippet is in AT&T syntax (where register names are prefixed with a `%`); in AT&T syntax operands order is generally *source, destination*, so

```
add %rbx, %rax
```

means "add rbx to rax" (i.e., in C it would be `rax += rbx`).

This is the opposite of Intel syntax, so if you were to see some snippet in Intel syntax, such as

```
add rbx, rax
```

(notice the absence of `%`) it would mean "add rax to rbx" (i.e. `rbx += rax`).

You can find a nice list of AT&T vs Intel syntax differences [here](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm).

Comment: Technically you can switch the `%` prefix separately from the flavor.

Comment: @Jester: ... but anybody doing so and then posting such code online would be generally regarded as a criminal.